# How do I return type hinting defined types

Tags: python, python-3.x, type-hinting

If I have the following:

```
def alert(self, text: str, color: str) -> str:
```

Can I get somehow the specified type of my arguments?

I tried using `func.__code__.co_varnames` & `inspect.getargspec(func)` without good results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `alert.__annotations__` has a dict with the types.

The key `return` describes the return value. All other keys are the names of the arguments.

Answer (score 1):

blue_note's answer won't work with `__future__.annotations`, introduced in python 3.7, use [typing.get_type_hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.get_type_hints) instead.